# Bash: if-statement string equal-to string1 OR equal-to string2

Tags: bash, unix, if-statement

I am trying to test if a string is not equal to either of two strings. For example, in C++, this would be written as:

```
if (string1 != string2 || string1 != string3)
```

However, attempting to create the Bash equivalent

```
if [ "$string1" != "$string2" || "$string1" != "$string3" ]
```

results in the error `[: missing ']'` and `(contents of string1): command not found`.

I'm not exactly too sure what is causing it, but searching didn't turn up any results I could use. It would be greatly appreciated if one could point out how the code I am using can be changed to suit the needs, and if possible, provide sample code.

Thanks in advance!
Harry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least three possibilities here:

```
if [ "$string1" != "$string2" ] || [ "$string1" != "$string3" ]
```

Or:

```
if [ "$string1" != "$string2" -o "$string1" != "$string3" ]
```

Or:

```
if [[ "$string1" != "$string2" || "$string1" != "$string3" ]]
```

Comment: Or `[[ "$string1" != "$string2" ]] || [[ "$string1" != "$string3" ]]`